# React mapped components inside render. How to not make it remap every re render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form that maps its components from a json file. My problem is when it rerenders it loads everything up again so it makes the system laggy.

Below is the structure of the json file.

I have a map loop in my `render()` to make them components. My problem is every time it re renders it remaps again so typing things is so laggy.

What is a better way to implement this?

```
const headers = [
    { header: "Basic Information", table: "basic" },
    { header: "Work Information", table: "work" }
];

const divisions = {
    basic: [{ header: "", name: "main" }],
    work: [{ header: "", name: "main" }]
};

const fields = {
    basic: {
        main: [
            {
                labelText: "Last Name",
                name: "lname",
                type: "text",
                shown: {
                    1: true,
                    2: true
                },
                md: 3
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

This is a snippet of the code I use to map the file in the render to make components

```
headers.map((header, key) => (
    divisions[header.table].map(division => (
            fields[header.table][division.name].map((field, key) => (
                    field.type == "text" ||
                    field.type == "number" ||
                    field.type == "email" ? (
                        <CustomInput
                            labelText={field.labelText}
                            id={field.name}
                            formControlProps={{
                                fullWidth: true
                            }}
                            errorText={
                                errors[field.name]
                                    ? errors[field.name]
                                    : null
                            }
                            success={
                                successes[field.name]
                                    ? successes[field.name]
                                    : null
                            }
                            helperText={
                                field.helperText
                                    ? field.helperText
                                    : null
                            }
                            inputProps={{
                                name: field.name,
                                type: field.type,
                                value: this.state[
                                    field.name
                                ]
                                    ? this.state[field.name]
                                    : "",
                                disabled: readOnly,
                                onChange: this.handleChange,
                                inputProps: {
                                    ...field.inputProps
                                }
                            }}
                        />
                    ) : null
            )
        )
)
))
```

Comment: Do you keep changing the JSON file and that's why everything keeps re-rendering ?

Comment: Please, post https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's unknown what happens inside the component.

Comment: @cloud_traveler I change the value in the state. And it rerenders

Answer (score 0):

Could you save the mapped version in the sate and only map if that state object is null/undefined?